# In which number set do I belong?

Tags: code-golf, math, number, classification

## Introduction

Mathematicians often work with number sets. These are groups of numbers that share common properties. These are number sets are, in order from most specific to most broad:

```
Natural numbers   (symbol N): These are the counting numbers: 1, 2, 3, ...
Integers          (symbol Z): These are all the numbers without a fractional part: ..., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
Rational numbers  (symbol Q): These numbers are the quotients of two integers, such as: 1.1 (11/10), 5.67 (567/100), or 0.333333333... (1/3)
-----The following two numbers sets are equally specific in describing numbers-----
Real numbers      (symbol R): These are positive, zero, and negative numbers, such as: π (3.1415926...), e (2.7182818...), or √2 (1.4142135...)
Imaginary numbers (symbol I): Numbers that give negative values when squared; for this reason they aren't very useful in everyday life.
                              These numbers contain the letter i in them, with i representing the √-1.
                              Examples: 2i, -1.5i 78i, 9i, -3.1415i, i
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Complex numbers   (symbol C): The sum of a real and an imaginary number in the form a + bi, examples: 2 + 7i, 3 + 3i, 1 - i, -8 + i
```

Note that when there is only a single `i`, it is not written `1i`.

## Challenge

Given a number from one of these number sets, print the symbol for the most specific number set that could describe it.

## Test cases

```
Input              Output
73.0            -> N
4/2             -> N
-73             -> Z
-1/3            -> Q
0.56            -> Q
0.555...        -> Q
0.123123123...  -> Q
3.1415926535... -> R
-1.37i          -> I
7892/5 + 23/4i  -> C
```

## Other info

- Natural numbers and integers may be given with a decimal point followed by a string of zeros
- To add on to the previous point, any input that can be converted into a simpler form shall have its output corresponding to the simplified input
- Rational numbers may be given with a `/` to represent a fraction, or a sequence of numbers occurring 3 or more times followed by `...`
- Numbers ending with `...` represent repeated decimals or un-terminated decimal real numbers
- Any number sets less specific than `Q` can also have inputs be given as a fraction
- You do not need to handle repeated decimals or un-terminated decimals for number sets other than Q and R
- Any error caused by lack of precision in floating point numbers will not invalidate a submission

This is code golf, so shortest code wins. If there is something unclear, let me know in the comments' section or edit the question.

Comment: I don't see how one could distinguish Q and R given the limited precision of machine numbers.

Comment: More fundamentally, it's not clear to me whether the inputs are number types in our languages, or strings of them. How much control do we have for how an input is given, in a language where, say, 0 can be represented as one of multiple number types? For example, when you say that inputs can be given as a fraction, do you mean that we have to handle inputs that might possibly be fractions, or this is a choice you can opt for? I think there's a lot of subtlety in specifying this challenge and suggest taking it the Sandbox.

Comment: What's the output of `-3/3`?

Comment: @xnor When I wrote "may", I meant that there exists a possibility. Should I clarify that?

Comment: @LuisMendo Very good point but I think you could have expanded. Indeed there are many machines employing only floating point that would say -3/3 = -0.999.. or possibly even 1.000...1. That's why many languages have different operators for integer and noninteger division, so the programmer gets to decide.

Comment: @LuisMendo@LevelRiverSt, I hope I have addressed that fact.

Comment: @xnor I hope the last bullet point addresses that.

Comment: @ericw31415 What I think xnor meant is: can we write the program and state "rationals are input with a `/`"? Or must the program be able to handle both `1/2` and `0.5` as input?

Comment: @ericw31415 I don't understand it. It seems like it allows treating R and Q interchangeably -- is that what you mean? And I'm even more confused now with "expression of possibility" vs "permission".

Comment: @xnor I was trying to say that such an input was possible. For some reason I can't seem to word it correctly though.

Comment: @xnor 3 repeats of a sequence of digits before the ... seems to be the distinguishing factor between them

Comment: _such an input was possible_ Again, _possible_ as in _you can **choose** to use it_, or as in _you **need** to support it_?

Comment: Suggested test case: `4/2 -> N` (my initial answer wasn't passing that one; now fixed)

Comment: `I` is irrational number set...

Comment: @user202729 Where'd you see that?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450524/is-there-an-accepted-symbol-for-irrational-numbers).

Comment: @user202729 From [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/number-types.html), I get `I` is imaginary, and from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Doublestruck.html) I get `I` is integers.

Comment: @LuisMendo I think users can use their judgment as clearly, the first test case and all the ones containing `/` would fail if they were not supported.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>121</s> 110 bytes

```js
s=>[...'QRCI'].find((_,i)=>[/(.+)\1\1\.\./,/\.\./,/.+[+-].*i/,/i/][i].test(s))||'QNZ'[k=eval(s),k%1?0:k>0?1:2]
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>[...'QRCI'].find((_,i)=>[/(.+)\1\1\.\./,/\.\./,/.+[+-].*i/,/i/][i].test(s))||'QNZ'[k=eval(s),k%1?0:k>0?1:2]

console.log(f('73.0'           )) // -> N
console.log(f('4/2'            )) // -> N
console.log(f('-73'            )) // -> Z
console.log(f('-1/3'           )) // -> Q
console.log(f('0.56'           )) // -> Q
console.log(f('0.555...'       )) // -> Q
console.log(f('0.123123123...' )) // -> Q
console.log(f('3.1415926535...')) // -> R
console.log(f('-1.37i'         )) // -> I
console.log(f('7892/5 + 23/4i' )) // -> C
```

#### Formatted and commented

```js
s =>                  // given the input string s
  [...'QRCI'].find(   // we first apply some regular expressions:
    (_, i) => [       //   i = index
      /(.+)\1\1\.\./, //     i = 0 (Q): 3x the same pattern, followed by '..' -> rational
      /\.\./,         //     i = 1 (R): '..' without the repeated pattern -> real
      /.+[+-].*i/,    //     i = 2 (C): a real part +/- an imaginary part -> complex
      /i/             //     i = 3 (I): just an imaginary part -> imaginary
    ][i].test(s)      //   this is a find(), so we exit as soon as something matches
  ) || 'QNZ'[         // if all regular expressions failed:
    k = eval(s),      //   assume the expression can now be safely evaluated as JS code
    k % 1 ?           //   if there's a decimal part:
      0               //     -> rational
    :                 //   else:
      k > 0 ?         //     if strictly positive:
        1             //       -> natural
      :               //     else:
        2             //       -> integer
  ]                   //
```

Comment: Very nice! I probably would not have been able to come up with a regex that fast.

Comment: Save 1 B using `(.+){3}` vs. `(.+)\1\1`

Comment: @EphellonDantzler This would match _any string of at least 3 characters_ instead of _3 times the same string_.